Not able to hit restresource URL from LWR community site
Issue: From my LWR community I am not getting the output from the restresource URL
I created one rest resource like as below code.
PS: I commented all my original logic and just trying with some test output.Once this is resolved I will uncomment
@RestResource(urlMapping='/userDetailApi/*')
global with sharing class OecoslAccountDetailAPI {

    @HttpGet
    global static void getUserDetail() {
      
         RestRequest restRequest = RestContext.request;
         RestResponse restResponse = RestContext.response;
         restResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         restResponse.statusCode = 200; // OK
         restResponse.responseBody=Blob.valueOf('{"test" : "test value"}');
      


        // String authToken=restRequest.headers.get('AuthorizationToken');
        // String[] parts = authToken.split('\\.');
        // restResponse.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        
        // // Decode Base64Url parts (Payload)
        // String payloadJson = decodeBase64Url(parts[1]);
        // OecoslUserDetailApiResponseWrapper response = new OecoslUserDetailApiResponseWrapper()
      

And I gave API enabled for the gust user license profile

And also gave APEX class access also to the profile.
When I tried to hit the restresource as like below URL I am getting 200 only but the output is coming as HTML and not seeing proper response
https://cadevXXX--XXXXXX.sandbox.my.site.com/ProviderPortal/services/apexrest/userDetailApi/


